# How to make a cluster of items based on membership?

Tags: python, list

I need like a magnet effect to form a cluster within a list of unique items.

My input is this :

```
lst1 = ['ah', 'ab', 'c', None, 'xo', 'i', 'b', 'lji', 'z', 'bel', 'oyb']
```

So based on a given item (a string that could be of any length), we need to move from left and right (towards this item) every string that contains it. For simplicity, lets consider the chosen item as a single letter : `letter = 'b'`. Now, we need to look for any string that contain `b` and bring it closer to it (from both sides) and preserve its suborder, like magnet. The other items will also be shifted `(-+)`.

In this case, the output should be :

```
lst2 = ['ah', 'c', None, 'xo', 'i', 'ab', 'b', 'bel', 'oyb', 'lji', 'z']
```

The cluster is represented here by the slice : `['ab', 'b', 'bel', 'oyb']`.

I tried the code below but I got a wrong list even though I was able to make the cluster :

```
letter = 'b'
data = {}
for i, e in enumerate(lst1):
    if e is not None and letter in e and e!=letter:
        data[e] = i
        
left = lst1.index(letter)-1
right = lst1.index(letter)+1

for key,value in data.items():
    if value<lst1.index(letter):
        lst1[left] = key
        left -= 1
    elif value>lst1.index(letter):
        lst1[right] = key
        right += 1
```

Here is what I got :

```
print(lst1)

['ah', 'ab', 'c', None, 'xo', 'ab', 'b', 'bel', 'oyb', 'bel', 'oyb']
```

Do you have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use list slicing + sorting:

```py
letter = "b"
lst1 = ["ah", "ab", "c", None, "xo", "i", "b", "lji", "z", "bel", "oyb"]

index = lst1.index(letter)

out = (
    sorted(lst1[:index], key=lambda v: letter in v if isinstance(v, str) else False)
    + [letter]
    + sorted(lst1[index + 1 :], key=lambda v: letter not in v if isinstance(v, str) else True)
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['ah', 'c', None, 'xo', 'i', 'ab', 'b', 'bel', 'oyb', 'lji', 'z']
```

Answer (score 1):

One option can be something like this, where I am forcing the "magnet" sublist in the middle and appending and pre-pending the rest of the list :

```
lst1 = ['ah', 'ab', 'c', None, 'xo', 'i', 'b', 'lji', 'z', 'bel', 'oyb']
char = 'b'
if char in lst1: # check if the letter exists in the list
  idx = lst1.index(char)
  sublist = [x for x in lst1 if (x is not None) and (char in x)] # get subset of elements that have 'b' in them
  opplist = [x for x in lst1 if (x is None) or (char not in x)] # opposite of sublist
  idx_sub = sublist.index(char)
  new_list = opplist[:idx-idx_sub] + sublist + opplist[idx-idx_sub:] # add sublist in the middle

print(new_list)
```

Ouput:

```
['ah', 'c', None, 'xo', 'i', 'ab', 'b', 'bel', 'oyb', 'lji', 'z']
```

Answer (score 1):

First slice the input list into two sublists: the items before and after `letter`.

Then separate each of these into subsets that do or don't contain `letter`.

Finally, concatenate all these together into the result.

```
index = lst1.index(letter)
before = lst1[:index]
after = lst1[index+1:]

before_match = []
before_nomatch = []
for item in before:
    if isinstance(item, str) and letter in item:
        before_match.append(item)
    else:
        before_nomatch.append(item)

after_match = []
after_nomatch = []
for item in after:
    if isinstance(item, str) and letter in item:
        after_match.append(item)
    else:
        after_nomatch.append(item)

result = before_nomatch + before_match + [letter] + after_match + after_nomatch
```

Answer (score 1):

With single traversal and auxiliary sub-lists:

```
def cluster_by(lst, target):
    before_seq, after_seq, core_seq = [], [], []
    head = True
    curr = None
    for v in lst:
        curr = before_seq if head else after_seq
        if not isinstance(v, str) or not target in v:
            curr.append(v)
        elif target != v:
            core_seq.append(v)
        else:
            core_seq.append(v)
            head = False
    return before_seq + core_seq + after_seq


letter = "b"
lst = ["ah", "ab", "c", None, "xo", "i", "b", "lji", "z", "bel", "oyb"]

print(cluster_by(lst, letter))
```

---

```
['ah', 'c', None, 'xo', 'i', 'ab', 'b', 'bel', 'oyb', 'lji', 'z']
```

---

Time performance comparison:

`cluster_by` (mine), `cluster_sorted` (Andrej), `cluster_Barmar` (Barmar)

```
print(timeit('cluster_by(lst, letter)', globals=globals(), number=10000))
print(timeit('cluster_sorted(lst, letter)', globals=globals(), number=10000))
print(timeit('cluster_Barmar(lst, letter)', globals=globals(), number=10000))
```

---

```
0.008141049998812377
0.015801682995515876
0.010250120001728646
```